# Google Play Store Hangs at Every Step

Tags: google-play-store, bugs, troubleshooting

This week, the Google Play Store is behaving very strangely. It can download *or* update a single app but not both without being killed!

There was an update for Chrome this morning, so I went to Google Play Store and clicked on the *Update* button. It then downloads the app, reaching 100% pretty quickly and hangs there forever, OK well I let it do that for an hour or so (but tried overnight with previous updates). Then, if I *Force Stop* the *Google Play Services* and restart it, it automatically does the install in a few seconds. If I try again to update another app, it downloads to 100% and hangs.

This very strange. Up to last week everything was working fine and no new apps were installed but there was about 9 or 10 updated. Since then, I must download and update one at a time, killing the Google Play Store between each!

Versions involved:

- Android 7.0 Kernel 3.18.31 Build NPP25.137-76
- Phone is rooted, has been for over a month.
- Google Play Store 8.1.30.S-all
- Google Play Services 11.5.17 [UPDATED]
- Google Play Services for Instant Apps 1.20-release-166886311 (WTH is this?, don't remember seeing it before)

How can I fix this and have Google Play Store working normally again?

Used to be able to install and update many apps without killing the Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue too. But I dont use any google stuff and didnt found back then a solution. Maybe deleting Cache or all data helps. If not working try deactivate>rebootactivate or uninstall all updates and do solution #2

Comment: Unfortunately, clearing all data did not change the behavior, it still hangs at each step which is very annoying. Deleting just the cache did not work either.